# UrlFetch equivalent of CURL -u "<username>:<password>"

Tags: curl, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have experience making CURL calls in GAS using `headers` and `payload`, but I have never done a CURL command using the `-u` option before.  According to the API spec, I must use the `-u` option.  I just don't know how to convert that to GAS.  Here is my code so far:

```
function updateStatus()
{ 
  //Build header.
  var header =
  {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', //Set content type to JSON.
  };

  //Put it all together.
  var options =
  {
      'method'     : 'get',    
      'headers'    : header     
  };

  //Make Login call to When I work.
  var responseGetPlan = UrlFetchApp.fetch('my url', options);
  var strResponseGetPlan = responseGetPlan.getContentText();
  Logger.log('Get Plan Response: ' + strResponseGetPlan); //Log response.

  var parsedData = JSON.parse(strResponseGetPlan); //Parse into JSON format.
  var strId = parsedData.id;  
  Logger.log(strId);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`curl -u` uses Basic authentication, which is a simple base64 encoding of a concatenated "username:password" string. You would send the following as headers.

```
Authorization: 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode('username:password')
```

#### References:

- [RFC7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#page-5)
- [curl Basic Authentication](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#Basic_Authentication)
- [Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64Encode(String))